# Evaluation of sum/asymptotic expansion of $\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \sum_{d \mid n, d = \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor} 1$

Tags: number-theory, summation, asymptotics

This sum arises from my calculations on quadratic factoring.  We can write

$$S \left({N}\right) =
\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \sum_{d \mid n, d = \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor} 1 =
\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \left[{\frac{n}{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}\rfloor}} \in \mathbb {Z}}\right]$$

where $\left[{...}\right]$ are Iversion brackets.  Numerical testing shows that the approximate answer is

$$S \left({N}\right) \approx 3 \lfloor{\sqrt{N}}\rfloor - 2$$

Now the number of perfect squares of $\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor$ over the interval from $n = 1$ to $N$ is $\lfloor{\sqrt{N}}\rfloor$.  So $S \left({N}\right) \ge \lfloor{\sqrt{N}}\rfloor$.  Obviously $S \left({N}\right) \le N$.  I am not making any further progress.

It looks like with the second form of $S \left({N}\right)$ that I am calculating the probability that $n/\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor$ is an integer.

I am looking for an exact answer if possible and the asymptotic limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

One more form using GCD function is

$$S \left({N}\right) = \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \left[{1 < \gcd \left({n, \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor}\right) = \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor}\right]+{\delta}_{N=1}+2 {\delta}_{N = 2}+3{\delta}_{N \ge 3}$$

Where the Kronecker delta functions are for the corrections for $N = 1$, $N = 2$, and $N \ge 3$.

So perhaps a restatement is for a given $n$ what is the probability that $1 < \gcd \left({n, \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor}\right) = \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor$ then sum over $n$.

Applying the answered results the exact answer is

$$S \left({N}\right) =
- 1
+ \lfloor{\sqrt{N}}\rfloor
+ \lfloor{\sqrt{N + 1}}\rfloor
+ \lfloor{\frac{1}{2} \left({- 1 + \sqrt{4\, N + 1}}\right)}\rfloor$$

The corresponding asymptotic expansion is

$$S \left({N}\right) \sim 3 \sqrt{N} - \frac{3}{2} + O \left({\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}}\right)$$

Comment: The sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \sum_{d \mid n, d = \sqrt{n}} 1$ is missing a floor. It should be $d=\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor$

Comment: Corrected thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is not a square then

$$n=m^2+a, \qquad 0<a \le 2m$$

So $m|n$ implies $n=m(m+1)$ or $n=m(m+2)$

Therefore, you are asking for $$\sum_{m^2 \le N }1+ \sum_{m(m+1) \le N }1+ \sum_{m(m+2) \le N }1= \begin{cases}3\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor-2\text{ for }N\in [m^2,m^2+m)\\ 3\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor-1 \text{ for }N\in [m^2+m,m^2+2m)\\3\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor \text{ for }N=m^2+2m\end{cases}$$

Comment: Very nice solution, I was not thinking in that direction.